# UItableView scrolled to bottom after InsertRows and animate inserting above existing rows in ios Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm trying to insert 30 items in a UITableView, but when new items are inserted while scrolling, the content automatically scrolls down. How to fix it? You can reply using swift

```html
  
public async void Update()
{          
NSIndexPath[] arr = null;
Items[] news = null;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
      news = DownLoadService.GetNewItems();
        if (news != null)
        {
        var l = list.Length;
        arr = new NSIndexPath[news.Length];
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
            arr[i] = NSIndexPath.Create(0, i + l);
            }
        }
    });
TableData.BeginUpdates();
list = list.Union(news).ToArray();
TableData.InsertRows(arr, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);
TableData.LayoutIfNeeded();
TableData.EndUpdates();              
}
```

Call to Update

```
    public override void WillDisplay(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCell cell, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (indexPath.Row == itemclick.getLength()-10)
            table.Update();
    }
```

[Visualiation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwJuC.gif)

Comment: If you want to load more data when the tableview scroll to bottom , you should call  `if (indexPath.Row == itemclick.getLength()-1)` (not 10) .

Comment: @Lucas Zhang - MSFT  if (indexPath.Row == itemclick.getLength()-10) when the tenth item from the end becomes visible, the download begins. Automatic scrolling to the end of the table after inserting items is a problem

Comment: You can download the data firstly ,and when scroll to bottom, insert them to the dataSource .

Comment: @Lucas Zhang - MSFT Thanks. It is work. I download new items when tenths item is visible, and insert new items when last item become visible

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**
iOS has **NSRunLoop** and it has five modes ,as we can seen in following image

[image]

The default mode is **NSDefaultRunLoopMode** .When you scroll the tableview , it will change to **UITrackingRunLoopMode** .However , the download event still works on default mode.So it will be conflict with scrolling .

**Solution:**

You can download the data firstly ,and when scroll to bottom, insert them to the dataSource . For example

```
public override void WillDisplay(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCell cell, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
        if (indexPath.Row == itemclick.getLength()-10)
            // download the data

        if (indexPath.Row == itemclick.getLength()-1)
        {
            //insert the data to source and reload the tableview .
        }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks  @Lucas Zhang 
Solution is download new items when tenths item is visible, and insert new items when last item become visible